# Basic Question about Hartshorne's definition of "locally of finite type".

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

In chapter 2.3, Hartshorne defines a morphism $f: X \to Y$ to be locally of finite type if there is an open affine cover $\{V_i\}$ of $Y$ and open affine covers $\{U_{ij}\}$ of $f^{-1}(V_i)$ so that $\mathscr{O}_Y(V_i) \to \mathscr{O}_X(U_{ij})$ makes $\mathscr{O}_X(U_{ij})$ a f.g. algebra over $\mathscr{O}_Y(V_i)$.

My question is, what is this homomorphism? The only way it seems to obtain this is via a restriction under the assumption that $U_{ij} \subseteq f^{-1}(V_i)$. Then, we can compose the natural $\mathscr{O}_Y(V_i) \to \mathscr{O}_X(f^{-1}(V_i))$ and the restriction $\mathscr{O}_X(f^{-1}(V_i)) \to \mathscr{O}_X(U_{ij})$. This assumption is not part of the definition, though. How would we find this map if $U_{ij} \not\subseteq f^{-1}(V_i)$? The definition of "open cover" I am familiar with only requires $f^{-1}(V_i) \subset \bigcup_{j} U_{ij}$ but the condition in hartshorne seems to assume equality.

I must be missing something. I know that open affines form a base for the topology on $X$ so $f^{-1}(V_i) = \bigcup_{j} U_{ij}$ would not be a very strange condition. Is that the condition I should assume when hartshorne says that $\{U_{ij}\}$ is an open cover of $f^{-1}(V_j)$?

Thank you!

Comment: "open affine covers $\{U_{ij}\}$ of $f^{-1}(V_i)$" means that each $U_{ij}$ *is* (by assumption) a subset of $f^{-1}(V_i)$ (and moreover that $f^{-1}(V_i) = \bigcup_j U_{ij}$, and also that each $U_{ij}$ is affine). What other interpretation did you have of the term "open cover"?

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose my confusion comes from the ambiguity of the topological space the "open cover" is taken in. If it is taken in the subspace/subscheme $f^{-1}(V_i)$, then that assumption would be clear. I interpreted the open cover to be in $X$, though, which must have led to the confusion.

Comment: That's a reasonable confusion! But since the definition only makes sense with one of these interpretations, we should assume it's that one :)

Comment: @DanielApsley one thing to keep in mind is that yes, $\bigcup_{i,j} U_{ij}$ is absolutely $X$. It's just that the definition is talking about the fact that once we fix $i$, the union $\bigcup_j U_{ij}$ covers $f^{-1}(V_i)$. So one just has to be a bit careful about what you mean by an multiply-indexed family of sets in curly braces, and whether you're quantifying over one index or both.